# mercurial: ignore .h generated from .idl

Tags: mercurial, idl, hgignore

is it possible to use .hgignore in mercurial to ignore header files generated from idl files?

I have a very large project in VS2008 and, by default, the midl tool generates .h files from .idl files in the same folder and with the same name. Naturally, I do not want the generated files controlled. Is it possible to configure mercurial to ignore a xxx.h file if there is xxx.idl file in the same folder?

Is there any other solution to my problem? Renaming the files for those ~100 projects would take ages and is not really an option I want to consider...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stevevls pointed out you can just ignore all .h files and then manually add the .h files you do want tracked (`hg add` overrides ignores).

Another option would be to put something like this in your `.hg/hgrc`

```
[ui]
ignore.generated = .hgignore-generated
```

and then create that file either manually or with a hook so that it lists all the generated .h files.  The file could be tracked or untracked at your option.  On unix this would auto create that file:

```
find . -name '*.idl' | sed 's/\.idl$/.h/ >| .hgignore-generated
```

I've no idea how to script that on windows, but one imagines powershell can do it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible.  .hgignore is very flexible and accepts globs and regexes.  You could probably get away with :

```
syntax:glob
*.h
```

See here for more details: http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgignore.5.html.

Comment: Sorry, I did not make myself clear. There is a lot of normal (not generated) .h files that I do not want ignored.

Comment: I see.  In that case, if you can't identify your files with a pattern or a specific location, mercurial can't really help you out.  You could try programatic creation of the .hgignore file if you can hook into the midl tool somewhere...